# WS2022 BSOD HTTP.sys

Tags: windows-server-2022

Good afternoon,

Our main DC out of the blue started restarting ending to BSOD with the error of "system thread exception not handled" caused by http.sys

I have already tried a clean boot, a BIOS update, a replacement of HTTP.sys from the file retracted from the same server's yesterday's backup, disabled the IIS service from safe mode, runned sfc and dism without any luck in restoring the server. I also checked for any windows updates that might have caused this but couldn't locate anything with today's or yesterday's date on it.

Any suggestions or help over this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, removed any thirdparty firewall or software that impact your network stack, and test again

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using ESET file security so the firewall in use is the native windows one. Apart from that there are no other 3rd party software that I can think of that would affect the network stack.